# При вызове команды docker-compose build ошибка read /home/usr/docker-compose-dir/.env: is a directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

В директории с `docker-compose.yaml` есть директория `.env` в которой содержится конфигурационный файл системы.
И при запуске любой команды `docker-compose`, появляется ошибка, что `.env` это директория. Если переименовать `.env` в `.env1`, то все проходит, но это не решение, я не могу отказаться от этого имени.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос сам текст docker-compose.yaml. Нам с этой стороны монитора не видно :)

Comment: А предполагается использование каких-нибудь .env файлов докер-компоузом? Он по дефолту пытается прочитать .env в директории рядом с конфигом проекта.